# truncate method returns &amp instead of &

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have something like below in my `view` file.

```
<%= ss.name + " - " + truncate(ss.description, length: 10) %>
```

Now my `ss.description` has **&** but this `truncate()` returns as `&amp`.

How can I remove this and keep it as **&**.

Comment: Try `<%= ss.name + " - " + truncate(ss.description, length: 10, escape: false) %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `escape: false` should do the trick

```
<%= ss.name + " - " + truncate(ss.description, length: 10, escape: false) %>
```

***Example:***

```
helper.truncate("<p>Once upon a time in a world far far away & around</p>", length: 300, escape: false)
 => "<p>Once upon a time in a world far far away & around</p>"
```

And ***without*** `escape: false`

```
helper.truncate("<p>Once upon a time in a world far far away & around</p>", length: 300)
 => "&lt;p&gt;Once upon a time in a world far far away &amp; around&lt;/p&gt;"
```

See [***Apidoc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate) for more Info.

Comment: It did with `escape:false` . Thanks

Comment: hey, BTW is there any way to truncate selected value from the dropdowns?

Comment: @Suraj I don't know. May be ask another question. You will get help :)